# problems with float in java libgdx android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

ok i using libgdx for android game development and i have a AI which moves depending on value of variable "ENEMYSPEED". Initally the value is set as

```
static float EnemySPEED = 0.5f;
```

and everything works fine. so i perform a simply compute like this

> EnemyVector.y -= EnemySPEED

Everything fine so far...

Now i feel my AI is moving fast and i decrease the variable value from 0.5f to 0.4f and i perform the same operation of decrement and it doesn't decrement!

What is going on??!!!

EDIT:

```
private void EnemyMove()
{
    EnemySection = findSection(Enemy);
    if(EnemySection == PlayerSection)
    {
        if(EnemyVector.x > PlayerVector.x) EnemyVector.x -= EnemySPEED;
        else if(EnemyVector.x < PlayerVector.x) EnemyVector.x += EnemySPEED;        
        else if(EnemyVector.y > PlayerVector.y) EnemyVector.y -= EnemySPEED;
        else if(EnemyVector.y < PlayerVector.y) EnemyVector.y += EnemySPEED;
    }
    else if(EnemySection == 1 ||EnemySection ==  3) EnemyVector.x += EnemySPEED;
    else if(EnemySection == 2 ||EnemySection ==  4) EnemyVector.x -= EnemySPEED;
    else if(EnemySection == 5)
    {
        if(EnemyVector.y > 212 || EnemyVector.y < 75)
        {
            if(PlayerSection == 1 ||PlayerSection ==  3) EnemyVector.x -= EnemySPEED;
            else if(PlayerSection == 2 ||PlayerSection ==  4) EnemyVector.x += EnemySPEED;  
        }
        else
        {
            if(PlayerSection == 1 ||PlayerSection ==  2) EnemyVector.y += EnemySPEED;
            else if(PlayerSection == 3 ||PlayerSection ==  4) EnemyVector.y -= EnemySPEED;
        }
    }

    if(Player.overlaps(Enemy)) System.out.println("Target Acquired!");  
    System.out.println(EnemyVector.x + "," + EnemyVector.y);
}
```

findSection finds in which quadrant the Enemy or player is in depending on parameter passed.

EDIT 2: i just noticed that it only works for 0.5,1,1.5 not any value in between. Is this some kind of limitation?

Comment: Please provide more contextual code. The above contains no errors.

Comment: I'm confused. Your "Everything is fine so far" and the change you make don't seem to make sense.  If it's fine up until you perform the operation, it seems like you're saying `-=` *increases* the speed. But then why is everything fine? You also "feel", but is it *actual*?

Comment: IOW, feeling like it's faster is different than debugging the code and *knowing* it's faster. Debugging it, BTW, should clue you in on the happenings; no?

Comment: by faster literally what i meant is how much X's in XY co-ordinate it moves

Comment: This is basically my whole AI code is

Comment: Are you positive you're satisfying the booleans you think you are? Perhaps you've swapped an `<` for an `>`, or similar? On a side note I hope you edited so all this magic is for clarification!

Comment: ok the problem i am getting is at the Y-axi's since in libgdx the origin is at the bottom left i want my AI to go top i.e. Y must increase

Comment: it works fine when EnemySPEED  = 0.5 and not when EnemySPEED = 0.4 or 0.3

Comment: I would suggest, for the sake of the post, to avoid adding additional information in the comment area. If it's important change/add it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys i am sorry the problem was with comparing two floats... :/

for example comparing 127.8 and 127.0 is obviously wont work.

i changed the code to this and it worked fine... don't know how i missed this.. lesson learned

Anyways thank you friends for your help..

```
if((int)EnemyVector.x > (int)PlayerVector.x) EnemyVector.x -= EnemySPEED;
        else if((int)EnemyVector.x < (int)PlayerVector.x) EnemyVector.x += EnemySPEED;      
        else if((int)EnemyVector.y > (int)PlayerVector.y) EnemyVector.y -= EnemySPEED;
        else if((int)EnemyVector.y < (int)PlayerVector.y) EnemyVector.y += EnemySPEED;
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as 'correct' so others will know you don't need an answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try and make the `EnemySPEED` as `volatile`. It might be the case that `EnemySPEED` is getting cached by the thread which is executing this code, and hence you are unable to see the difference when you change the `EnemySPEED` from `0.5` to `0.4`.

Comment: but EnemySPEED is not changed dynamically.. from beginning to the end  of the game it doesn't change.

Comment: I thought that when you said that you decrease the variable value from 0.5 to 0.4, it meant dynamic decrement. :D

Comment: not i am sorry if i wasn't clear i just change the value and rebuild the project again